# Is there a simple source code viewer plugin for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

for example

```
    setMediamixDefaultTime(mediamixVO);

    boolean booked = false;
    Long campaignSeq = mediamixVO.getCampaignSeq();
```

when I want to know about how to declared setMediamixDefaultTime() method,
I have to jump to setMediamixDefaultTime() declaration line.
It's very annoying especiouly source code is long..

so I need that is, 
if I move mouse to that method or keyboard shortcut, the method declaration popup in small window.

Answer (score 0):

just crtl+click on the item you want to jump to.

There is also an outline view, which shows the program structure.

Answer (score 0):

Control + mouse click on the method will take you to the method declartion and you can use the back button to come back to the previous code.

Again the shortcut for back button is Alt + left arrow

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Declaration View if you don't want to lose your place, but the Navigate menu's "Last Edit Location", Back, and Forward actions may also work.